# Present perfect tense and present continous tense

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Can we use present perfect tense and present continuous tense in one sentence for example.

I have been tossing and turning all night because I have drunk much coffee.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine. Although there's nothing wrong with this sentence, to say you have drunk much coffee may sound stilted or archaic in the US. In the US it would be much more common to say you have drunk **a lot of coffee**.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah it's ok.
In my opinion, nevertheless, if you're no longer drinking at the time, maybe it would be better to use simple past form simply by saying:

> ... I drank much coffee

Comment: I drank much coffee doesn't sound correct to me. I would consider "I drank a lot of coffee" or "I drank too much coffee".

Comment: yeah, you're right, I just wanted to focus on the structure of the sentence. Too much coffee, so much coffee, a lot of coffee, etc, is another story.